# Performance of executorService multithreading pool

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using Java's concurrency library ExecutorService to run my tasks. The threshold for writing to the database is 200 QPS, however, this program can only reach 20 QPS with 15 threads. I tried 5, 10, 20, 30 threads, and they were even slower than 15 threads. Here is the code:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
List<Callable<Object>> todos = new ArrayList<>();

for (final int id : ids) {
    todos.add(Executors.callable(() -> {
        try {
            TestObject test = testServiceClient.callRemoteService();
    SaveToDatabase();
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }));
}
try {
    executor.invokeAll(todos);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {} 
executor.shutdown();
```

1) I checked the CPU usage of the linux server on which this program is running, and the usage was 90% and 60% (it has 4 CPUs). The memory usage was only 20%. So the CPU & memory were still fine. The database server's CPU usage was low (around 20%). What could prevent the speed from reaching 200 QPS? Maybe this service call: `testServiceClient.callRemoteService()`? I checked the server configuration for that call and it allows high number of calls per seconds.

2) If the count of id in ids is more than 50000, is it a good idea to use invokeAll? Should we split it to smaller batches, such as 5000 each batch?

Comment: Is it possible to post the type of queries that are being executed? I.e. are they all accessing or modifying the same row or table? Are they all reads, all writes, or a combination of the two?

Comment: You are doing a remote call, that will probably take a lot of time (network overhead etc. etc). The number of threads is limited by the number of cores you have (you have 4 CPU's but how many cores?). If the remote call takes a lot of time, the core is waiting for a response and will not be available for anything else. Creating more threads than cores will probably slow your whole system down as it needs to start to switch.

Comment: @M.Deinum "The number of threads is limited by the number of cores you have ... If the remote call takes a lot of time, the core is waiting for a response and will not be available for anything else." - This is at least misleading. Of course, you can have much more *threads* than CPU *cores* at any point in time; and *especially* when one threads needs to wait for I/O (network,disk,...) ("blocked") another ("runnable") thread will get swapped in to use the CPU in the meantime. Hence, especially if you have relatively much waiting in a thread you want to use *more* threads to keep the CPU busy.

Comment: That depends on your CPU architecture. Also more threads will eventually lead to swapping out threads, which in java will lead to quite a performance hit as the stack and everything else needs to be serialized/deserialized upon pausing and unpausing the thread. Also using a lot of threads for IO heavy operations is rarely a good solution (it is for CPU intensive operations). So indeed it isn't limited by the number of cores but creating 200 threads where you only have 16 cores will probably make your program even slower then with only using 20 threads.

Comment: @M.Deinum "performance hit as the stack and everything else needs to be serialized/deserialized upon pausing and unpausing the thread." - I have no idea what you are talking about. Java threads map 1:1 onto operating system threads and there simply is no such thing as "serializing/deserializing" the stack, or "pausing" a thread. And as I said, you won't gain performance by using many threads if each thread can already use 100% CPU. Multi-threading is just *the* way to mask I/O latencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum "creating 200 threads where you only have 16 cores will probably make your program even slower then with only using 20 threads." - If each of those threads spends 90% of its time waiting for network or other I/O, 20 threads will only fully use 20*(100%-90%)=2 CPU cores...

Comment: On a hardware level 1 core will handle 1 thread. If it needs to switch to another thread, the state belonging to that thread needs to be stored in-memory (this takes time). Then it will clear the state at the cpu level and fill it for the thread it needs to proces next. This context switching is a heavy operation. That is what I meant with serializing/deserializing.

Comment: Each thread in Java will also allocate additional memory depending on your JVM settings , so creating many threads will also allocate a lot of memory. Which might lead to excessive GC cycles and pauses leading to further performance degradation.

Comment: @M.Deinum A context switch on a modern CPU incurs a very small penalty. The bigger issue often is the loss of locality of memory accesses which may more or less invalidate the data cache. But this has nothing to do with Java, and is not a big issue in most cases. E.g. even if the penalty was 1ms in total, waiting 5ms for a network response is still a good time to switch to another thread.

Comment: @M.Deinum "creating many threads will also allocate a lot of memory. " - It depends on what you call "a lot". IIRC, default stack size is/used to be 1MB per thread. "Which might lead to excessive GC cycles" - No. A thread's stack is *not* allocated from the heap in which Java objects reside and thus does not cause any GC cycles.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in this code which prevents this query rate, except creating and destroying a thread pool repeately is very expensive. I suggest using the Streams API which is not only simpler but reuses a built in thread pool

```
int[] ids = ....
IntStream.of(ids).parallel()
                 .forEach(id -> testServiceClient.callRemoteService(id));
```

Here is a benchmark using a trivial service. The main overhead is the latency in creating the connection.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(0);
    Thread service = new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            for (; ; ) {
                try (Socket s = ss.accept()) {
                    s.getOutputStream().write(s.getInputStream().read());
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    service.setDaemon(true);
    service.start();

    for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int[] ids = new int[5000];
        IntStream.of(ids).parallel().forEach(id -> {
            try {
                Socket s = new Socket("localhost", ss.getLocalPort());
                s.getOutputStream().write(id);
                s.getInputStream().read();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("Throughput " + (int) (ids.length * 1e9 / time) + " connects/sec");
    }
}
```

prints

```
Throughput 12491 connects/sec
Throughput 13138 connects/sec
Throughput 15148 connects/sec
Throughput 14602 connects/sec
Throughput 15807 connects/sec
```

Using an ExecutorService would be better as @grzegorz-piwowarek mentions.

```
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
    for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int[] ids = new int[5000];
        List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>(ids.length);
        for (int id : ids) {
            futures.add(es.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    Socket s = new Socket("localhost", ss.getLocalPort());
                    s.getOutputStream().write(id);
                    s.getInputStream().read();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));
        }
        for (Future future : futures) {
            future.get();
        }
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("Throughput " + (int) (ids.length * 1e9 / time) + " connects/sec");
    }
    es.shutdown();
```

In this case produces much the same results.

Comment: It's just ForkJoinPool shouldn't be used for IO, I think so

Comment: @GrzegorzPiwowarek possibly not, but it is simple to use. Using an ExecutorService is most likely to be better after you get this working.

Comment: Might be worth noting that you use "localhost" in your example, which likely is orders of magnitude faster than remote networking, basically making the tasks completely CPU-bound. If each network connection just caused each thread to have to wait for a few ms for the response, the scaling effect of more threads would be more apparent.

Comment: @JimmyB and DB request are likely to take even longer adding more benefit to a larger pool size. +1

Answer (score 1):

Why do you restrict yourself to such a low number of threads?

You're missing performance opportunities this way. It seems that your tasks are really *not* CPU-bound. The network operations (remote service + database query) may take up the majority of time for each task to finish. During these times, where a single task/thread needs to wait for some event (network,...), another thread can use the CPU. The more threads you make available to the system, the more threads may be waiting for their network I/O to complete while still having some threads use the CPU at the same time.

I suggest you drastically ramp up the number of threads for the executor. As you say that both remote servers are rather under-utilized, I assume the host your program runs at is the bottleneck at the moment. Try to increase (double?) the number of threads until either your CPU utilization approaches 100% or memory or the remote side become the bottleneck.

By the way, you `shutdown` the executor, but do you actually wait for the tasks to terminate? How do you measure the "QPS"?

One more thing comes to my mind: How are DB connections handled? I.e. how are `SaveToDatabase()`s synchronized? Do all threads share (and compete for) a single connection? Or, worse, will each thread create a new connection to the DB, do its thing, and then close the connection again? This may be a serious bottleneck because establishing a TCP connection and doing the authentication handshake may take up as much time as running a simple SQL statement.

> If the count of id in ids is more than 50000, is it a good idea to use
>   invokeAll? Should we split it to smaller batches, such as 5000 each
>   batch?

As @Vaclav Stengl already wrote, the Executors have internal queues in which they enqueue and from which they process the tasks. So no need to worry about that one. You can also just call [`submit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)) for each single task as soon as you have created it. This allows the first tasks to already start executing while you're still creating/preparing later tasks, which makes sense especially when each task *creation* takes comparatively long, but won't hurt in all other cases. Think about `invokeAll` as a convenience method for cases where you already have a collection of tasks. If you create the tasks successively yourself and you already have access to the `ExecutorService` to run them on, just `submit()` them a.s.a.p.

Answer (score 0):

About batch spliting:
`ExecutorService` has inner queue for storing tasks. In your case `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);` has 15 thread so max 15 tasks will run concurrently and others will be stored in queue. Size of queue can be parametrized. By default size will scale up to max int. InvokeAll call inside of method `execute` and this method will place tasks in to queue when all threads are working.

Imho there are 2 possible scenarios why CPU is not at 100%:

1. try to enlarge thread pool
2. thread is waiting for `testServiceClient.callRemoteService()` to 
    complete and meanwhile CPU is starwing

Answer (score 0):

The problem of QPS maybe is the bandwidth limit or transaction execution(it will lock the table or row). So you just increase pool size is not worked. Additional, You can try to use the producer-consumer pattern.